# libgdx first time user.Error in runnable 'Creating Gradle model'

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

So, I create a new project with libgdx (for desktop,android,iOS,html and at extensions,I got set Box2d.
I generate the project,all seems to be ok, but when I import the project in eclipse, it gives me this error:

Error title: Error in runnable 'Creating Gradle model'
Error message: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 See error log for details.

Anyone has any idea about this?

Once again ,I specify -it's my first time using this and I followed the documentation steps ,from libgdx's website. ( http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html )

Comment: http://pixelscientists.com/blog/posts/error-in-runnable-creating-gradle-model

Comment: I found this earlier today and it did not help me :/
Thank you for the reply though.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this exact problem you're having, and I found the solution elsewhere on this site:
[Error at building model of new Gradle project for libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085045/error-at-building-model-of-new-gradle-project-for-libgdx/26109153#26109153)

It seems there's a current incompatibility between the latest release version of Eclipse (4.4.1) and the latest release version of the Gradle Eclipse plugin (3.6.1). This problem is reportedly fixed in the 3.6.2 development build of the Gradle plugin, so you could install the development build if you wanted, but being a development build who knows what else might be broken in it.

I opted for the solution outlined in the other question here, which was to add the following lines to the end of the eclipse.ini file for your Eclipse install:

```
-Dosgi.configuration.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area=@user.dir
```

After I did this and restarted Eclipse, I was able to import my Gradle project.

Comment: Thanks. I actually gave up on libgdx for now,but the information seems to be valid and the solution works so yea.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened with me,Here is how i resolve.
first of all it's quite easy.

[Follow 3 steps]
**step 1:** just connect to the internet and then click on build model.
**step 2:** It will start downloading a zip file.
**step 3:** After that restart eclipse.

enjoy coding...
:)

Answer (score -1):

Create file local.properties in project's folder (one that you are trying to import)
in that file enter this:

sdk.dir=C:/path to my android/sdk

Then try to Build Model again.

It worked for me.