# Error with gradle building model

Tags: java, android, eclipse, spring, gradle

Building a model with gradle in eclipse 4.4.1 (luna) gives me an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project '10-VideoServiceWithMongoDB'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         :10-VideoServiceWithMongoDB:unspecified
      > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

 Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.454 secs
```

running it through a command line through jettyRun I can get more information

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:461)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:202)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.updateClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:118)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:466)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$CompositeAction.execute(Actions.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$TransformingActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:442)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:437)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE.
Required by:
    :10-VideoServiceWithMongoDB:unspecified
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain.resolve(UserResolverChain.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.projectmodule.ProjectDependencyResolver.resolve(ProjectDependencyResolver.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver$StaticVersionResolveResult.resolve(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionSelectorResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:939)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DefaultModuleRevisionResolveState.getDescriptor(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:645)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:329)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:305)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:34)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:459)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache.process(RequestAuthCache.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:485)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.DefaultExternalResourceRepository.getResource(DefaultExternalResourceRepository.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.getResource(ExternalResourceResolver.java:572)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.findStaticResourceUsingPattern(ExternalResourceResolver.java:455)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.findResourceUsingPattern(ExternalResourceResolver.java:446)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.findResourceUsingPatterns(ExternalResourceResolver.java:368)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.findIvyFileRef(MavenResolver.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.getDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.getDependency(MavenResolver.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ExternalResourceResolverAdapter.getDependency(ExternalResourceResolverAdapter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository$1.run(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.getDependency(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleVersionRepository.getDependency(CachingModuleVersionRepository.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.IvyContextualiser$1.invoke(IvyContextualiser.java:44)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.getDependency(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain$RepositoryResolveState.resolve(UserResolverChain.java:185)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain.findLatestModule(UserResolverChain.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain.findLatestModule(UserResolverChain.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain.resolve(UserResolverChain.java:54)
```

I have read [this][1] but after adding the extra lines in my .ini file for eclipse, nothing changed.  I have tried changing my java version from 1.8 to 1.6openJDK. I am on Ubuntu 14.

**edit**

here's the build file

```
uildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7


war {
    baseName = 'videosvc-mongodb'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/milestone" }
}

dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")

    compile("com.google.guava:guava:17.0")
    compile("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.0")
    compile("commons-io:commons-io:2.4")

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

When I try to refresh the Gradle dependecy by running gradle -refresh--dependencies in the apps folder I get a new fun error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jake/mobilecloud-14/examples/10-VideoServiceWithMongoDB/build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project '10-VideoServiceWithMongoDB'.
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer.create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/gradle/api/Task;
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085045/error-at-building-model-of-new-gradle-project-for-libgdx
```

Comment: Add to your question your `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so apparently Gradle didn't like my java build. I switched it to java-7-oracle by using this [method](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)