# How does one migrate libGDX projects to another system?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I have libGDX projects on one laptop.  I need to move to another laptop.  I am using eclipse on both windows laptops.  I have a git repo I can push to and pull from.  I know that I can clone the https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-cuboc and import it into eclipse as a gradle project.  But when I try this with my libGDX projects the "Build Model" fails.

[image]

I suspect I did not export the project correctly from my source laptop.
Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Update:

OK. When I exported the projects from Eclipse I exported as plain old Android projects (`Export Android Application`), so I figured that I should export the project as `Generate Gradle build files` but I get this error when I attempt to do so ...

[image]

... and yes I did this too ...

[image]

... and I still get the same error.

UPDATE: After accepting JH's answer. Thank you for your answer BTW.

I was able to copy files in the project, but with gradle one copies the files into the directory libGDX generated the base project.  I was coping the files into my Eclipse workspace, which is why the files were not showing up in my Eclipse project ... I know confusing huh.  Well I was able to get my project to build but whenever I launched the app if crashed at runtime (see [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.glGenTexture:()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470101/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-not-found-com-badlogic-gdx-backen)) I decided to give up on Eclipse and migrate my project to Android Studio.  After taking a quick look at the Android Studio I was FINALLY able to build my app and execute it without runtime errors on my new laptop!

For clarity here is what I did to migrate my project from one laptop to another.

1) I got the my code out my git repo.

2) I downloaded the latest gdx-setup.jar, 1.5.3, from the libgdx project.

3) I generated a project, being careful to use the correct values for: Name, Package, Game class and Android SDK.  For Destination I used c:\Users\Me\.

4) I copied the directories android, core, html, desktop and ios directories from my git repo into the corresponding directories in the project that gdx-setup.jar created.

5) Then I started Android Studio and follow the directions found here: [Migrating to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

6) updated my build.gradle to include google play service and BANG! it worked

Comment: I found this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085045/error-at-building-model-of-new-gradle-project-for-libgdx/26109153#26109153.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately following the instructions in that answer did not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to export anything, just clone the git repository on the new computer and then import gradle project and build model.

You could even generate a new libgdx project with their project wizard and then copy the source files.

Comment: I wish eclipse would just let me copy the source into projects source directory, but eclipse does seem to pick up on the face that there are new files.  I can do the whole import thing file by file, but I have A LOT of files.  Maybe it is time for me to switch to Android Studio?

Comment: You must definitely can copy files like that, just click the project and press F5 (refresh).